# How can I find a blocking call inside Tornado webserver?

Tags: python, tornado

We have a service running on Tornado, it is written asynchronously. I suspect that somewhere in the code there is a blocking call that hurts performance.
Is there a way in Tornado to find this code section / function call?

Or can I find code that holds the `IOLoop` longer than X ms?

Thanks

Alex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python 3+ and Tornado 5+, set the environment variable `PYTHONASYNCIODEBUG=1`. In older versions of either Tornado or Python, call `IOLoop.current().set_blocking_log_threshold(0.5)`.

Either way, this will cause a message to be logged whenever a call blocks for more than half a second.